# Vue war: Expected Array, got Object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, vuejs2

I need create this object from PHP array and parse this to JSON to Vue object.

Vue object:

```
 options: [
        {
          language: 'Javascript',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Vue.js', category: 'Front-end' },
            { name: 'Adonis', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        },
        {
          language: 'Ruby',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Rails', category: 'Backend' },
            { name: 'Sinatra', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        },
        {
          language: 'Other',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Laravel', category: 'Backend' },
            { name: 'Phoenix', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

For exemple in php i have the next array:

```
$testArray = [
13 => [
    'language' => 'languageTest',
    'libs' => [30 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '30'],
               31 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '31'],
               32 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '32'],
    ]
],
14 => [
    'language' => 'languageTest',
    'libs' => [30 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '30'],
               31 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '31'],
               32 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '32'],
    ]
]
];
```

If I pass this to "json" I get the following result.

```
{"13":{"language":"languageTest","libs":{"30":{"name":"nameTest","id":"30"},"31":{"name":"nameTest","id":"31"},"32":{"name":"nameTest","id":"32"}}},"14":{"language":"languageTest","libs":{"30":{"name":"nameTest","id":"30"},"31":{"name":"nameTest","id":"31"},"32":{"name":"nameTest","id":"32"}}}}
```

This gives me the following error in a Vue component: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-option-groups

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got Object.

How can I create an array from PHP but when passed to JSON it is correct for the Vue component?

UPDATE: 
**I create this array recursively by assigning values.**

```
private function getChildCategoryTree($category, $level = 1, $maxLevel = 2)
{
    $arrayTreeCategory = [];
    if ($category->hasChildren()) {
        $childCategories = $this->getSubcategories($category);
        if (count($childCategories) > 0) {
            foreach ($childCategories as $childCategory) {
                if ($childCategory->hasChildren() && $level < $maxLevel && $childCategory->getId() != 14) {
                    if ($this->categoryCanShow($childCategory)) {
                        $subLevel = $level + 1;
                        $arrayTreeCategory[$childCategory->getId()]['language'] = $childCategory->getName();
                        $arrayTreeCategory[$childCategory->getId()]['libs'] = $this->getChildCategoryTree($childCategory, $subLevel);
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($this->categoryCanShow($childCategory)) {
                        if ($level == 1) {
                            $arrayTreeCategory[99]['language'] = 'other';
                            $arrayTreeCategory[99]['libs'] = ['name' => $childCategory->getName(), 'id' => $childCategory->getId()];
                        } else {
                            $arrayTreeCategory[$childCategory->getId()] = ['name' => $childCategory->getName(), 'id' => $childCategory->getId()];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $arrayTreeCategory;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The array that you pass is being converted to object in JS (as you use associative array in PHP).

If you don't care about the keys (13 and 14 respectively), just remove keys like so:

```
$testArray = [
    [
        'language' => 'languageTest',
        'libs' => [30 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '30'],
            31 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '31'],
            32 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '32'],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'language' => 'languageTest',
        'libs' => [30 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '30'],
            31 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '31'],
            32 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '32'],
        ]
    ]
];
```

**If you DO care about the ID, you have 2 options:**

Option 1 - move the id to the internal array, like so:

```
$testArray = [
    [
        'id' => 13,
        'language' => 'languageTest',
        'libs' => [30 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '30'],
            31 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '31'],
            32 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '32'],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 14,
        'language' => 'languageTest',
        'libs' => [30 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '30'],
            31 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '31'],
            32 => ['name' => 'nameTest', 'id' => '32'],
        ]
    ]
];
```

Option 2: Change the prop type to Object and make sure you apply some adjustments in your code so it would work as you first planned and designed.

Comment: Thanks for you response @MyLibrary. But how could I do it in the same way with a recursive method and adding data in the array? Update main post